# mongodb...Mongoose update nested sets... why is this so hard arg

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nested-sets

I'm trying to fix some data globally... Why am i getting this error...TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) { if (!(this instanceof model)) r

I am getting all the data and it should update, but its not. and the error is obtuse.

```
UpdateAllThings: function(req, res) {
    things.find().exec( function(err, items) {
        items.forEach(function(th) {
            th.Features.forEach(function(f) {
                thingsfeatures.findOne({'fName': f.fName},function(err, item) {
                    if (item != null ) {
                        try{
                            things.Update({Features: {"$elemMatch":{_id:f._id}}}, {$addToSet: {'Features.$.tType': item.tType, 'Features.$.fGroup': item.fGroup }}, function (err, inventory) {
                                if (err) return handleError(err);
                            });
                        }catch(err){
                            if (err) return handleError(err);
                        }

                    }
                });
            });
        });

    });
     return res.send('thanks please come again');
}
```

****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_****

sure: This is more or less it....

```
{
  "Features" : [{
      "_id" : ObjectId("5013c9742df16337609b2706"),
      "tID" : "5013c9742df16337609b26f4",
      "tName" : "Canon EOS T2i (Rebel T2i, Canon 550D) ",
      "fName" : "Retail Price:",
      "fValue" : "899.99",
      "_keywords " : ["899.99"]
    }, {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5013c9742df16337609b2707"),
      "_keywords " : ["1", "x", "Proprietary", "LP-E8", "Lithium-ion", "rechargeble"],
      "fGroup" : ["Power"],
      "fName" : "Batteries Included:",
      "fValue" : "1 x Proprietary LP-E8 Lithium-ion rechargeble",
      "tID" : "5013c9742df16337609b26f4",
      "tName" : "Canon EOS T2i (Rebel T2i, Canon 550D) ",
      "tType" : ["Cammera"]
    }],
  "_id" : ObjectId("5013c9742df16337609b26f4"),
  "tName" : "Canon EOS T2i (Rebel T2i, Canon 550D) ",
  "tType" : "Camera"
}
```

This Worked, but it added in an array with data and not just the new fields and data as i wanted.

```
db.things.update({"_id":ObjectId("5013c9742df16337609b26f4"), "Features._id" : ObjectId("5013c9742df16337609b2706") }, { $addToSet : { "Features.$.fType" : "Cammera", "Features.$.fGroup"  : "Power" }})
```

Comment: One problem I see:  `things.Update` should be `things.update`

Comment: Sun of a bitch. Thanks johnny... Arg I hate case sensitive languages.

Comment: But the thing is it is still not updating the records with the new fields and data... though I test the command and it is working.. well not throwing an error. db.things.update({ "Features" : { "$elemMatch" : { "Features._id" : ObjectId("5013c9742df16337609b2707") } } }, { "$addToSet" : { "Features.$.tType" : "Cammera", "Features.$.fGroup" : "Power" } })

Comment: > db.runCommand("getlasterror")
{
        "updatedExisting" : false,
        "n" : 0,
        "connectionId" : 2,
        "err" : null,
        "ok" : 1
}

Comment: Can you provide details on your schema?  It's very hard to figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: sure: 

db.things.update({"_id":ObjectId("5013c9742df16337609b26f4"), "Features._id" : ObjectId("5013c9742df16337609b2706") }, { $addToSet : { "Features.$.fType" : "Cammera", "Features.$.fGroup"  : "Power" }})

Comment: No, I mean update your original post to contain an example document; something that makes it clear how your documents are structured.

Comment: Your query looks fine to me for that document structure.

Answer (score 0):

Issue one Capitalization. Thanks Johnny

Issue Two: Addtoset creates array's and not add's to the set that is there it creates new set's. So just use set. (confusing documentation personaly)

Third: To update nested set's simply do it like this: This is much better then using elementmatch and other forms.

```
db.things.update({"_id":ObjectId("5013c9742df16337609b26f4"), "Features._id" : ObjectId("5013c9742df16337609b2706") }, { $set : { "Features.$.fType" : "Cammera", "Features.$.fGroup"  : "Power" }})
```